# What are the possible neural network architecture for linear regression or time series regression?

Tags: neural-networks, keras, regression, time-series

I started modeling a linear regression problem using dense layers (layers.dense), which works fine. I am really excited, and now I am trying to model a time series linear regression problem using CNN, but from my research in this link [Machine learning mastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/keras-functional-api-deep-learning/)

A CNN works well with sequence data, but my data isn’t sequential. My data set can be found here [Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57224353/is-my-training-data-set-too-complex-for-my-neural-network).

Is there a multivariate time series/ time series neural network architecture that I can use for time series linear/nonlinear regression?

Comment: That linked post is what you need. LTSM is an example.

Comment: Let me know if this problem has been solved and if I can delete the post.